# Jenkins Xvfb plugin - selecting incorrect -fbdir name

Tags: jenkins-plugins, xvfb

When running a build on a newly installed Jenkins server on centos7 The Xvfb fails with the following:

> Xvfb starting$ /bin/Xvfb -displayfd 2 -screen 0 1024x768x8 -fbdir
>   /var/lib/jenkins/xvfb-272-..fbdir6345857630426455925 FATAL: Cannot run
>   program "/bin/Xvfb": error=2, No such file or directory
>   java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

Compared to our original server, the name of the fmdir is different.  I believe it should be in the format `/var/lib/jenkins/xvfb-<build no.>-<unique number>.fmdir`

How is the `-fbdir` name being generated and what creates the directory?

This is on Jenkins

> 2.176.1 with Xvfb plugin 1.1.3 on Centos 7.6.1810

Answer (score 0):

```
Xvfb starting$ /usr/bin/Xvfb -displayfd 2 -screen 0 
1920x1080x24 -fbdir /var/lib/jenkins/xvfb- 
 214-..fbdir17701667040157463918
```

How is the -fbdir name being generated?

It's unique & random and the format is

```
/var/lib/jenkins/xvfb-<build no.>-..fbdir<random unique no.>
```

what creates the directory?

When job is executed, Jenkins check the Directory in which to find Xvfb executable i.e./usr/bin and it creates it's copy for it's use ( at location where Jenkins is installed i.e./var/lib/jenkins/xvfb-214-..fbdir17701667040157463918) where the memory mapped files containing the framebuffer memory should  be  created to perform all GUI operations in virtual memory.

```
-fbdir framebuffer-directory
```

This  option  specifies  the  directory  in which the memory mapped files containing the framebuffer memory  should  be  created.This option only exists on machines that have the mmap and msync system calls.

Refer:https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54763/xvfb-1.html